# How to remove only last empty element from array after spliting in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have an array which I split on basis of *comma* `","` but there is a last entry as empty because I am concatenating it in jquery. I used

```
Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

but it removes *all the empty entries* from an array e.g. 
if my array is

```
 "1"," ","2","3"," "
```

it returns `1,2,3`. But I want it to remove only the *last one* from it e.g.
return `1," ",2,3`. Is it possible to do it *without substracting* `1` from the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TrimEnd` method to remove whitespaces from end on the `String` instance before calling `Split`:

```
string input = "1,2,3, ,4, , ";
input.TrimEnd()
   .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**Output Array:**

```
["1"," ","2","3"," ","4"," "]
```

[See DEMO Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BHohpX)

Comment: to verify it:
    Console.Write(item+"I");      we can see It still consider a space as an element

Comment: Actually its result is `["1","2","3"," ","4"," "]`

Answer (score 2):

First, use `TrimEnd` to prevent the aforementioned edge case and then split:

```
input.TrimEnd(' ',',').Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: This looks like the best way. Except that it should be `StringSplitOptions.None` since he want to return `1," ",2,3`

Answer (score 2):

If we want to skip all whitespace only items starting *from end* let's `Reverse`, then  `SkipWhile` (as usual) the items we want to get rid of and, finally, `Reverse` back again:

```
  string input = "1,2,3, ,4, , ";

  ["1", "2", "3", " ", "4"]
  string[] array = input
    .Split(',') // it seems we don't want to remove empty in the middle
    .Reverse()
    .SkipWhile(item => item.All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
    .Reverse()
    .ToArray();
```

If you want all items except last one:

```
  // All items
  string[] array = input
    .Split(',');

  // Removing the last item: ["1", "2", "3", " ", "4", " "]
  Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this `Code` to remove last element (`if (Last_Element == " ")`) of array.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         // Simple Array:
         string[] array = new string[] { "1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , " "};

         // Converting Array into a List. (Because we don't have any remove method for array.)
         var arrayList = array.ToList();

         // Retrieving last element.
         string _lastSpace = arrayList.Last();

         // Confirmation: Last Element is space or not.
         if(_lastSpace == " ")
             arrayList.RemoveAt(arrayList.LastIndexOf(" "));

         // Converting the list without having last Element with space to "array"
         array = arrayList.ToArray();

    }
}
```